# Substitute Chrome tab content without connecting to server

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension and for certain tabs I need:

1. Prevent a tab from connecting to its URL
2. Show custom text within the tab
3. (UPDATE) Tab's URL to stay the same preferably

Please suggest a direction how to achieve both the goals.

What I have tried... I can prevent original content from loading:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(...
  return {cancel: true};
```

A technical page is shown then:

> Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension.
>   Try disabling your extensions.
>   ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

(Maybe it's possible to have a custom technical page?)

But this also prevents my content script from loading and thus I lose ability to alter tab's DOM.

Without `onBeforeRequest` I can show custom text in the tab via a content script, but Chrome still gonna request the original URL.

Comment: You can redirect to a data URL that embeds the page content.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of cancelling the request by returning `{cancel: true}`, redirect the request to a URL which contains your custom content by returning `{redirectUrl: "..."}`.

The easiest way of doing this will be to include a "request blocked" HTML document within your extension as [a web-accessible resource](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources). You can pass parameters to the document using query string arguments -- they are ignored when fetching web-accessible resources, but can be accessed from content scripts using `window.location.search`.

A notable example of an extension that uses this approach is [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm), which uses a web-accessible HTML page `document-blocked.html` as a substitute for blocked web pages.